# Join items in an array with two different delimiters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve a challenge on jshero.net. The challenge is :

> Write a function list that takes an array of words and returns a string by concatenating the words in the array, separated by commas and - the last word - by an 'and'. An empty array should return an empty string.

Example: `list(['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie'])` should return `'Huey, Dewey and Louie'`

Best solution I could come up with was this :

```
function list (a){   
  let myList = a.join(' and ' )
  return myList
}
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make the function to return just the "and" word just after the second name and not before it. Does anyone know how to solve this?
............................................................

Update : I found an alternative :

```
function list(arr){
    let myL= arr.slice(0,2);
    let myLi= myL.join(' , ')
    let myL2 = arr.slice(2,3);
    let myLi2= myL2.join(' and ');
    let myList = myLi + myLi2 
    if (arr.length <=2){
        return arr.join(' and ')} else {
            return myList}
}
```

I am close, the outcome is `"Huey , DeweyLouie"` but somehow is still not adding the "add" word into it. Anyone got an ideea?

Comment: How about 2-step approach?  First slice out the last element and join it with commas, and then join the result with the last element using "and"?

Comment: Like this? 

function list (a){
let toSlice = a.slice()
let myList = myL.join(' and ' )
return myList
}

Comment: You're going to have to use different logic depending on if you're on the last index or not, since you'll need to know whether to join with `, ` or `, and `. If you want an answer using fancy, modern JavaScript, take a look at [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Here's a one-liner: `list.reduce((acc, cur, i) => acc + cur + (i < list.length - 2 ? ', ' : i < list.length -1 ? ', and ' : ''), '');`

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Explain what relevant parts you can code do & explain about how you are stuck getting to your goal from there.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

```js
list.reduce((acc, cur, i) => acc + cur + (i < list.length - 2 ? ', ' : i < list.length -1 ? ', and ' : ''), '');
```

This is a more advanced example, since it uses some JavaScript specific functions that are less "general programming."

Here's an explanation:

```js
list
  .reduce(
    (acc, cur, i) =>            // start of an arrow function (implicit 'return')
      acc + cur +               // + as in string concatenation
        (
        i < list.length - 2 ?   // what to concatenate? comma or 'and'? 
          ', ' :                // if it's before the 2nd last index, use a comma.
          i < list.length - 1 ? // else, double check if it's the very last one.
            ', and ' :          // if it is, use ', and '.
            ''                  // else-else (the space AFTER the last index), put nothing.
        ),
      ''); // starter argument for 'reduce'
```

The [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function takes another function as its argument. That function will be run on each element in the list in order. On each subsequent element, the first argument (`acc`) will be whatever the function returned on the last item (in the case of the first item, it'll be the supplied starting arugment). This let's you gradually tack the each element (`cur`) onto the value that follows through the array.

Using ternaries lets you make it a one liner. If you wanted it to be more verbose:

```js
const list = ['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie']

const output = list.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  let str = acc;
  str += cur;
  
  if (i < list.length - 2) {
    str += ', ';
  } else if (i < list.length - 1) {
    str += ', and ';
  }
  
  return str;
}, '');

console.log(output);
```

If you're new to programming in general, this may seem a bit overwhelming (I know `reduce` did for me, too). But, if you're familiar with programming practices, this is a good example of a JS-specific way to do things.

Cheers, and good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting use case. In fact I thought it would be a nice addition to my tagged templates library!

So we have two separators:

- delim: `', '`
- delimlast: `' and '`

And a few cases:

- `[]` -> `''`
- `['Huey']` -> `'Huey'`
- `['Huey', 'Dewey']` -> `'Huey and Dewey'`
- `['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie']` -> `'Huey, Dewey and Louie'`

Here's one way to approach this:

```js
const list =
  (xs, delim = ', ', delimlast = ' and ') =>
      !Array.isArray(xs) ? xs
    : xs.length === 0    ? ''
    : xs.length === 1    ? xs[0]
    : xs.length === 2    ? xs[0] + delimlast + xs[1]
                         : xs.slice(0, -1).join(delim) + delimlast + xs[xs.length-1];


list('Huey');                     // 'Huey'
list([]);                         // ''
list(['Huey']);                   // 'Huey'
list(['Huey', 'Dewey']);          // 'Huey and Dewey'
list(['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie']); // 'Huey, Dewey and Louie'
```

---

*I am the author of a small library of tagged templates (yet another one!) and your question gave me the idea for another one. Thanks!*

```js
import {list} from '<DETAILS CAN BE FOUND IN MY PROFILE IF YOU ARE INTERESTED>';

const guys = ['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie'];
list`Hey ${guys}!`;
//=> "Hey Huey, Dewey and Louie!"
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach will be to iterate over till the last -1 array values and add "," to them.

When reached the last-1 of the list add the "and" outside the loop