# UPDATE:Join items in an array with two different delimiters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have posted a few days ago a question about a challenge that I did on jshero.net:
The link for the question is [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434975/join-items-in-an-array-with-two-different-delimiters)

I feel like I am close, the best answer I could come up with is:

```
function list(arr){
    let myL= arr.slice(0,2);
    let myLi= myL.join(' , ')
    let myL2 = arr.slice(2,3);
    let myLi2= myL2.join(' and ');
    let myList = myLi + myLi2 
    if (arr.length <=2){
        return arr.join(' and ')} else {
            return myList}
} 
list(['Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie'])
```

Now if I use this code it will return `'Huey , DeweyLouie'`. Do you have any idea on how to get the right answer?

Comment: I am really sorry about this, I though that if I could just link up the previous question it would be enough. Next time, I will post the entire question with the solutions I come up with and error messages. Again, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just slice to the last element, and then append last element.  Add a few checks for edge cases.
Seems like a really trivial problem.  Not sure why all the overly complicated solutions.  Am I misunderstanding the problem?

```js
list = l => l.length > 1 ? l.slice(0,-1).join(', ') + ` and ${l.pop()}` : l[0]||''

console.log(
list(['Huey','Dewey','Louie'])
)

console.log(
list(['Huey','Dewey'])
)

console.log(
list(['Huey'])
)
```

Comment: I am new to javascript and I am trying to learn on my own as much as I can. Maybe the solution is simpler than I though it would be but I've been dealing with this challenge for the past three days.I am not quite sure how to get past it.